# NSIS copy file that doesn't exist but will be created

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to copy a file from a folder that doesn't exist in the beginning but will be created before copying.

```
Name "Test Installer"
OutFile "testinstaller.exe"
InstallDir C:\dev\NSIS\Scripts\Testinstaller

Section "copyTest"
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
    CreateDirectory $INSTDIR\test
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR\test
    File test2\test.txt
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
    File /nonfatal test\test.txt
SectionEnd
```

The problem is that the compiler creates and error when he tries to compile and can't find the file. But when the file created before compiling and deleted after compiling the program works.

Comment: Your example code makes little to no sense to me. You are creating a folder `test` into which you want to extract the file `test2\test.txt` (remember, that's the location on *your* computer from which you include the file). Then you change the `$OUTDIR` to do what – extract the same file again? You could either use the same File command again (or copy it from the prior location). The NSIS compiler is smart enough to include the same file twice.

Comment: The problem is solved! I use CopyFiles instead of File now. I used this program for testing purpose. In my real programm I install a software and have to copy a folder that is created while installing into a higher level directory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`File`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/File.md) command includes a file into your installer, hence it must exist at compile time. You can [`CopyFiles`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/CopyFiles.md) to copy files at runtime.